# Xml File structure error within C# application

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm beginner in `Linq To Xml` , i'd like to create a new Xml file with this structure:

```
 XDocument doc = new XDocument(

        new XElement("files",
         new XElement("cam",data.CamFile),
         new XElement("modele",data.CamFile)
                     ),
         new XElement("parametre",
         new XElement("scoremin",data.Scoremin),
         new XElement("cupidite",data.Cupidite),
          new XElement("frameaxes",data.Frameaxes),
         new XElement("Npyramid",data.Npyramid))

         );
```

But this exception `This operation would create an incorrectly structured document.` appears.

1. What is the reasons of this error?
2. How can i fix it??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you will apply proper formatting, you'll see that you are trying to define two root elements:

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument(
    new XElement("files",
        new XElement("cam", data.CamFile),
        new XElement("modele", data.CamFile)
    ),
    new XElement("parametre",
        new XElement("scoremin", data.Scoremin),
        new XElement("cupidite", data.Cupidite),
        new XElement("frameaxes", data.Frameaxes),
        new XElement("Npyramid", data.Npyramid)
    ));
```

That is not allowed in XML. XML document must contain one element that is the parent of all other elements. This element is called the root element (see [XML Syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp)). Either make `parametre` nested element of `files`:

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument(
    new XElement("files",
        new XElement("cam", data.CamFile),
        new XElement("modele", data.CamFile),
        new XElement("parametre",
            new XElement("scoremin", data.Scoremin),
            new XElement("cupidite", data.Cupidite),
            new XElement("frameaxes", data.Frameaxes),
            new XElement("Npyramid", data.Npyramid)
    )));
```

Or wrap both in some other element:

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument(
    new XElement("root",
        new XElement("files",
            new XElement("cam", data.CamFile),
            new XElement("modele", data.CamFile)
            ),
        new XElement("parametre",
            new XElement("scoremin", data.Scoremin),
            new XElement("cupidite", data.Cupidite),
            new XElement("frameaxes", data.Frameaxes),
            new XElement("Npyramid", data.Npyramid)
    )));
```